# New dual boot of Ubuntu 17.04, no wifi, no additional drivers availabl

Tags: dual-boot, internet, 17.04, additional-drivers

Any help? I recently installed a dual boot of Ubuntu 17.04 alongside my Windows 10. I use a USB adapter to get my internet working in Windows 10, but in Linux it's a different story.

lsusb:

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 13b1:0042 Linksys
```

Comment: What is the USB adapter? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Please POST the output to your question if you really want help. How can anyone answer if you don't tell what adapter you are having trouble with?

Comment: What do you mean? Like everything it resulted with?

Comment: If you know which line shows your dongle, you can post only that line. If you are not sure, post all output.

Comment: This is a year-old post. I don't know if anything has been done since. https://askubuntu.com/questions/799104/unable-to-get-linksys-wusb6100m-wireless-adapter-to-work

Comment: How exactly can I add ndiswrapper to my machine with no internet? Sorry if this sounds like a newbie question :P

Comment: You can't use `ndiswrapper` with this card. It is not supported. Even with internet connection.

Comment: I see. I will have to wait some time to be able to have support for my internet. Well, there goes me using Ubuntu

Comment: You can get another dongle that is supported.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any money. Good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wireless adapter is not supported by Linux. It is an ath10k USB device. The ath10k driver does not have USB support yet.

For very advanced users I can give a link to a patch enabling USB support, but it needs some work to apply to a specific kernel.

https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg158150.html

I don't think a regular user can make any use of this patch.

Some time later the USB support should be added to mainline.