# New Ubuntu desktop wireless setup

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have a linksys WUSB6100M wireless usb adapter that I can't seem to get working on my new Ubuntu install.

I tried the linksys website and they basically had nothing but windows drivers available.

Found a forum that had a link and terminal install for drivers for the modem in that adapter that did not work either.

It looks like it might be supported on the ubuntu help website but cant seem to find the correct drivers to get it working.

Is this one of the few usb wireless adapters that just wont work with Ubuntu/linux?

Comment: Exactly which release of Ubuntu did you install?

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/799104